# jquery widget loops through all inputs

Tags: jquery, loops, widget

I'm trying to create my first jquery widget that adds an 'x' to clear inputs. It works but it's very slow once I click on the 'x' to clear the input. I think it's because it's loops through all the inputs everytime but I don't know how to prevent this from happening.

Is the looping the problem or is there something else wrong?

```
(function($, undefined) {       
$.widget("jomojo.clearmojo", {
    version: "1.0",
    options: {
        disabled: null,
        icons: {
            primary: null,
            secondary: null
        }
    },

    _create: function(){
        $('input[type=text]').addClass('clearable');
        $('input[type=text]::-ms-clear').css('display', 'none'); 

        this.eventNamespace = "." + this.widgetName + this.uuid;

        function toggle(value){
            return value ? 'addClass':'removeClass';
        };

        this.document
            .on('mouseenter', '.clearable', function(){
                if (options.disabled){
                    return;
                };

                if ($(this).prop('disabled')===false){
                    $(this)[toggle(this.value)]('x');
                };
            })
            .on('mousemove', '.x', function(event){
                $(this)[toggle(this.offsetWidth-18 < event.clientX-this.getBoundingClientRect().left)]('onX');
            })
            .on('mouseleave', '.x', function(){
                $(this).removeClass('x');
            })
            .on('click', '.onX', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).removeClass('x onX').val('').change();
                $(this).trigger('keyup');   
            });
    }, // end create
});
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: FYI, your `toggle` function is just like jQuery's `toggleClass` function.

Comment: The only time it loops through all the inputs is when you create the widget. I don't see any loop when you click on the `onX`.

Comment: Using delegation for events like `mousemove` is likely to slow down the application. Every time you move the mouse anywhere, it has to run the handler and test whether the mouse is over the selector that you delegated to.

Comment: It would be better if you attached your widget to specific divs or forms, then you could bind the delegation to that element, rather than `document`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the input and suggestions... I'll look into the toggleClass.

Comment: @Barmar  I don't get why it loops either... when I add an alert it returns the correct element id but repets it the same amount of times as the number of inputs, if that makes sense.

Comment: Not sure about delegation and attaching the widget but i'll see what I can find and try to apply your suggestions.

Comment: BTW it's only slow once I click the 'x' to clear the input.

Comment: Show how you're using the widget. Can you make a [Stack Snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0) or jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Barmar never created a jsfiddle with a jquery widget.. this is as closs as I got http://jsfiddle.net/1x9w4ehx/14/

Comment: I fixed your fiddle so it loads jquery-ui to get the widget factory. And it has to call the widget in the Javascript panel so it runs after the widget is defined. But the widget is getting an error because `input[type=text]::-ms-clear` is not a valid jQuery selector.

Comment: Couldn't you tell from the error message in the Javascript console? Please don't tell me that you're trying to debug Javascript without opening the console.

Comment: What I working on is a Sketchup plugin which runs a watered down version of the default browser and there's no way that I know of to get a console. Which makes my Learning curve that much harder on trying to learn this stuff.

Comment: I'm able to recreate the problem... as soon as I wrap the inputs in a form with an id it 'loops' http://jsfiddle.net/1x9w4ehx/55/

Comment: You're doing `$("input[type=text]").clearmojo()`, which calls the widget initialization function once for each input. Then inside the initialization function, you bind the event handlers to every `.clearable`, `.x`, and `.onX`, not just the one that you called the widget on. So if there are 3 inputs, you'll bind the event handlers 3 times on each of those elements. You should just bind the event handlers on the element that the widget was called on.

Comment: Which is what i think 'this.document' does, correct? I've been trying to replace that with no luck so far.

Comment: `this.document` is the entire document. I think you should just be doing `$(this).on("mouseenter", function() ...)`, and the function should check whether the element has the appropriate class for that event.

Comment: I've tried that and I can't get the '.on('mouseenter')' to fire at all... only time it works is with this.document.

Comment: The basic problem is that the way you've written the code isn't as a widget. It should just be a plain function.

Comment: You're right, as a plain function it works but I wanted to try and learn to write a widget and ironically I thought this would be a simple code to learn with! Ha!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/1x9w4ehx/66/ shows the basic structure. In a widget factory, `this` is the widget instance, not the element, you need to use `this.element` to refer to the element. I haven't got it completely working, but it should get you on the way.

Comment: I had tried 'this.element' but never thought of trying '$(this.element)'. Thanks, I'll post the working code when I'm done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Barmar, here's the working code I came up with. Used toggleClass as he suggested and also added some conditions as to when the code should work on an input.

```
(function($, undefined) {       
    $.widget("jomojo.clearmojo", {
        version: "1.0",

        _create: function(){
            $('input[type=text]').addClass('clearable');

            this.element
                .on('mouseenter', function(){
                    if ($(this).prop('disabled')===false && $(this).val()!='' && $(this).prop('readonly')===false){
                        $(this).toggleClass('x');
                    };
                })
                .on('mousemove', function(event){
                    if ($(this).prop('disabled')===false && $(this).val()!='' && $(this).prop('readonly')===false){
                        $(this).toggleClass('onX', this.offsetWidth-18 < event.clientX-this.getBoundingClientRect().left);
                    };
                })
                .on('mouseleave', function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('x');
                })
                .on('click', function(event){
                    var elementOffsetWidth=this.offsetWidth
                    var parentOffset=$(this).parent().offset();
                    var relativeX=event.pageX-parentOffset.left;
                    var xOffset=elementOffsetWidth-16

                    if ($(this).prop('disabled')===false && $(this).val()!='' && $(this).prop('readonly')===false && relativeX>xOffset){
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $(this).removeClass('x onX').val('').change();
                        $(this).trigger('keyup');
                    };
                });
        }, // end create
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Also need to add the following in the css code to disable the clear function from IE, i think from v10+. If this needs to be done for other browsers please add the code. If there's a way to add this to the widget code also please chare the code.

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear{
    display: none;
}

.clearable{
    background: #fff url('../images/delete.jpg') no-repeat right -10px center;
    background-size: 10px 8px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    transition: background 0.4s;
}

.clearable.x{
    background-position: right 3px center;
}

.clearable.onX{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```